# How do I check if a RSS feed is working?

Tags: php, rss

For example, if there is an RSS feed and for some reason it is down or cannot be grabbed I want to display a simple message saying "feed cannot be grabbed".

Right now PHP spits out a really ugly warning message.

note:I do not need to know whether it is valid. I just need to know if the feed actually works. I do not want to turn off warnings. I want to spit out a simple echo if the feed is not working. I am using PHP no libraries.

Any thanks would be awesome!

Rick

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) can you provide us with some example code that triggers the error? and what error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks. Right now everything is working fine, but say I am pulling a feed from http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportplayer_uk_edition/football/rss.xml

and they change thier structure to http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportplayer_uk_edition/soccer/rss.xml

football and soccer paths have been switched. The feed will no longer work, which I can fix easily, but I just want a simple "Can't grab feed right now" so the users don't see a dom document load error.

Rick

Comment: $this->xml = $feed_name;
$this->xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$this->xmlDoc->load($this->xml); //code fails here when it doesn't exist
$this->init();

Answer (score 0):

You can manually handle any XML parsing errors by using the [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://docs.php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) function.

An example can be found [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php)

Comment: That was helpful, but I am still getting this error. (The url is an incorrect one, so I could test)

Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://rss.cnn.com/rss) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Feed not found error: FeedBurner cannot locate this feed URI. in /home/content/r/i/c/rickchendesign/html/twg/rssLib.php on line 17

Comment: Indeed it seems that there is no way to suppress the error when using DOMDocument (I thought you were using SimpleXML) "cleanly". You could create a custom PHP error handler for it. Though admittedly that seem rather ugly and I feel PHP really should have made it easier to handle warnings in this case.

Comment: I should have used Simple XML. I started this project as a learn PHP project. At least I learned. Thanks for your help Inspire.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
error_reporting(E_WARNING);

if (!$xmlDoc->load($url)){ 

 echo ("Not content could be loaded.");

}
```